# Overwrite file on upload if file exists

Tags: php, joomla-3.4

I am using a multiupload component/plugin for Joomla/VM, i have already modified the code to prevent it rename files (as my product image names contain the product name and sku). However, if the file already exists in the images folder, then the file is suffixed with (1). I would like to overwrite the file if it has the same name, or deleted it before uploading. I think i have found the function in the component which does this, but i'm relatively new to this and i'm not sure what part of code i need to modify? Here is the function:

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->name = $this->get_file_name($name, $type, $index, $content_range);
        $file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval($size));
        $file->type = $type;
        if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
            $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
            $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
            if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
                mkdir($upload_dir, $this->options['mkdir_mode'], true);
            }
            $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);
            $append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
                $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);
            if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
                // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
                if ($append_file) {
                    file_put_contents(
                        $file_path,
                        fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND
                    );
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                }
            } else {
                // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                    $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                );
            }
            $file_size = $this->get_file_size($file_path, $append_file);
            if ($file_size === $file->size) {
                $file->url = $this->get_download_url($file->name);
                list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);
                if (is_int($img_width) &&
                        preg_match($this->options['inline_file_types'], $file->name)) {
                    $this->handle_image_file($file_path, $file);
                }
            } else {
                $file->size = $file_size;
                if (!$content_range && $this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                    unlink($file_path);
                    $file->error = 'abort';
                }
            }
            $this->set_additional_file_properties($file);
        }
        return $file;
    }
```

$name contains the filename of the image to be uploaded. Any help would be most appreciated.

Best Regards
Donna

Edit: Here are the 2 additional functions.

```
protected function get_upload_path($file_name = null, $version = null) {
    $file_name = $file_name ? $file_name : '';
    if (empty($version)) {
        $version_path = '';
    } else {
        $version_dir = @$this->options['image_versions'][$version]['upload_dir'];
        if ($version_dir) {
            return $version_dir.$this->get_user_path().$file_name;
        }
        $version_path = $version.'/';
    }
    return $this->options['upload_dir'].$this->get_user_path()
        .$version_path.$file_name;
}
```

and

```
 protected function validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index) {
        if ($error) {
            $file->error = $this->get_error_message($error);
            return false;
        }
        $content_length = $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval(
            $this->get_server_var('CONTENT_LENGTH')
        ));
        $post_max_size = $this->get_config_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
        if ($post_max_size && ($content_length > $post_max_size)) {
            $file->error = $this->get_error_message('post_max_size');
            return false;
        }
        if (!preg_match($this->options['accept_file_types'], $file->name)) {
            $file->error = $this->get_error_message('accept_file_types');
            return false;
        }
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            $file_size = $this->get_file_size($uploaded_file);
        } else {
            $file_size = $content_length;
        }
        if ($this->options['max_file_size'] && (
                $file_size > $this->options['max_file_size'] ||
                $file->size > $this->options['max_file_size'])
            ) {
            $file->error = $this->get_error_message('max_file_size');
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->options['min_file_size'] &&
            $file_size < $this->options['min_file_size']) {
            $file->error = $this->get_error_message('min_file_size');
            return false;
        }
        if (is_int($this->options['max_number_of_files']) && (
                $this->count_file_objects() >= $this->options['max_number_of_files'])
            ) {
            $file->error = $this->get_error_message('max_number_of_files');
            return false;
        }
        list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($uploaded_file);
        if (is_int($img_width)) {
            if ($this->options['max_width'] && $img_width > $this->options['max_width']) {
                $file->error = $this->get_error_message('max_width');
                return false;
            }
            if ($this->options['max_height'] && $img_height > $this->options['max_height']) {
                $file->error = $this->get_error_message('max_height');
                return false;
            }
            if ($this->options['min_width'] && $img_width < $this->options['min_width']) {
                $file->error = $this->get_error_message('min_width');
                return false;
            }
            if ($this->options['min_height'] && $img_height < $this->options['min_height']) {
                $file->error = $this->get_error_message('min_height');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Edit 2: I have tried to add a file_exists() to the handle_file_upload function:
//Check if file exists
  $exist_file = $file_path.$uploaded_file;
    if file_exists($exist_file) {
       unlink($exist_file);
               }

But the files do not upload at all. I have spent hours on this and i really haven't a clue.

Comment: I have found something about setting the FILE_APPEND flag is this related? $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0

Comment: I can't see anything in this code that check if the file already exists. However it foes call 2 other functions that you may want to check in the same file: `get_upload_path` and `validate`. Maybe see if the code for the check exists in either of these functions

Comment: @Looder I'll have a look, i have found this on the PHP site: If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set. FILE_APPEND is mentioned twice in this function, do you know how i can unset it? I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: I have included the additional functions

Comment: @Lodder i'f messed about with the FILE_APPEND and i don't think it is related to that, as if i remove it the file doesn't upload at all. I'll keep looking :)

Answer (score 2):

If I am interpreting what the developer did here correctly this may work for you. These changes should be made in the first code you posted.

Add this code:

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
```

Before this code:

```
$file = new stdClass();
```

And add this code:

```
$append_file = false;
```

After this code:

```
$append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
            $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);
```

Then add this:

```
if(is_file($file_path)){
    JFile::delete($file_path);
}
```

Before this:

```
move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Terry, it has been the most constructive so far. Unfortunately, it is still appending the (1) at the end. The developer is not responding to emails either so i'm really stuck, i'm honestly not sure why someone would want a random file name generated rather than the file name of the image, its not good seo. Anyway, i will add the full file code to the post and fingers crossed the community can find a solution. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You may want to take a look at the handle_image_file() function as well. That may be where the number is being appended to the name.

Comment: I just posted a comment but unfortunately it does not appear here. The full code can be found at https://github.com/Dtorr1981/joomla.git upload.php...sorry if this isnt aloud on here.

Comment: Just for giggles try the steps I have outlined above now. They have changed a little bit.

Comment: I have edited the file, and this seems to break the code as the files do not upload at all. I have emailed the developer again, but if you have any more ideas i would be most appreciative.